# Simplest way of getting a bootable linux flash drive + VM in Windows

Tags: windows, usb-drive, live-usb

I realize tools for making a flash drive image that boots a linux system (for example ubuntu) are common enough.

I'd like to get a flash drive like that that also lets me use the system inside of Windows, without administrator privileges.  I don't know if that's even technically possible...

In other words, if I hop onto a public computer running Windows and insert my flash drive, I want to jump into my linux system without rebooting the computer, and without administrator privileges in Windows.

Is that technically possible? If so are there tools (distro-specific tools are ok) that will make me such a flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing, as whatever virtualization method you use, even something link colinux, requires administrative privileges. So if you cannot reboot and do not have administrative privileges, you won't be able to use a usb flash drive. You need to find a different solution such an ultraportable, or some tablet, or just your smart phone with an ssh client, if you do not want to carry around your heavy laptop.